# How to display view while doing a background process on android

Tags: android, multithreading, web-services, view, android-activity

I'm having a minor problem and I don't know how to do it.
I created a app, that pulls information through an xml web service.
The data get's parsed and inserted into a local sqlite database.
Everything works so far.
Due to the size of the data (that varies based on the pulled information) I intended to insert a loading screen with a progressbar and a spinner to notify the user that actions are taken.
Well let's say it, that it is planed to work this way.

My Problem is, that it is displayed, as soon as the work is done, not bevor.
This is how I've done it:

```
Handler phHandle = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){
            int progress = msg.arg1;
            pb.setProgress(progress);
        }
    };
    class firstInitHandler implements Runnable{
          private Handler phHandle;
          public void setHandle(Handler h){
              this.phHandle = h;
          }
          public void run(){
                try {
                    firstInit i = new firstInit();
                    i.doInit(this.phHandle);
                    if(i.isResult())
                    i.doParse();
                    if(i.isData()){
                        i.doTasks();
                        i.doEquipment();
                        i.doUser();
                        i.doCompany();
                        i.doForms();
                        i.doSysconfig();
                    }
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
          }
    }
    firstInitHandler h = new firstInitHandler();
    h.setHandle(phHandle);
    h.run();
```

This is part of a method.
Well it works so far.
The thread for processing the information is visible in task manager in the sdk.
I can also see the status messages on logcat that are created while the debug system works.
But the screen stays blank and only is displayed as soon as the task is done.
I'm a little bit confused and don't know where to start to have the waiting screen work.

I would welcome any help.

Chris

Comment: Could a splash screen be what you are looking for? You are able to display whatever you want on the screen, for the duration of the background tasks that are going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried looking at the Android Developers resources?

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) is the [Dialog tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). A progress dialog example is shown on this page, or you could hop to the specific progress dialog section where it shows all the possible commands, usages, etc.

Hope this is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AsyncTask fot this to work smoothly....

Inside your activity define the AsyncTask ....

then you can call the AsyncTask from onclick or inside onCreate in this way

```
new loading().execute();
```

The AsyncTask class will be as below.

- The basic concept is to initialize the progress dialog in
  onPerExecute().
- Do the heavy stuff (non UI ) like parsing and all in
  DoInBackground().
- Then dismiss the dialog in onPostExecute().
- you cannot do the UI changes in DoinBackGround, but you can do that
  in OnPre / OnPostExecute().

the class is as follows.

```
 private class loading extends AsyncTask'<'String, Integer, Boolean>

{

ProgressDialog dialog ;
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                    if(result==true) 
                    {  

                     dialog.dismiss();

                    }

                }

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onPreExecute();

                   dialog = new ProgressDialog(current.this);
                            dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                            dialog.show();

                }

                @Override
                protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                }

                @Override
                protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    try {
                        firstInit i = new firstInit();
                        i.doInit(this.phHandle);
                        if(i.isResult())
                        i.doParse();
                        if(i.isData()){
                            i.doTasks();
                            i.doEquipment();
                            i.doUser();
                            i.doCompany();
                            i.doForms();
                            i.doSysconfig();
                        }
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) 
                       {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return false;
                        }
                     return true;


                }



            }
```